# I am running into an error message while trying to compile my pizza order program

Tags: java

The program is not wanting to compile for some reason.

I've tried declaring separate topping variables for each additional topping but that only occurred to produce more errors than I had before.

```
System.out.println("Would you like pepperoni added? (Y/N): ");
numberOfToppings = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
if (numberOfToppings == "Y" || numberOfToppings == 'y') {
  numberOfToppings = numberOfToppings + 1;
  toppings = toppings + "and pepperoni.";
} else {
  numberOfToppings = 0;
}
//Prompt for sausage and store in numberOfToppings
System.out.println("Would you like sausage added? (Y/N): ");
numberOfToppings = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
if (numberOfToppings == "Y" || numberOfToppings == 'y') {
  numberOfToppings = numberOfToppings + 1;
  toppings = toppings + "and sausage.";
} else {
  numberOfToppings = 0;
}
//prompt for onion and store in numberOfToppings
System.out.println("Would you like onion added? (Y/N): ");
numberOfToppings = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
if (numberOfToppings == "Y" || numberOfToppings == 'y') {
  numberOfToppings = numberOfToppings + 1;
  toppings = toppings + "and onion.";
} else {
  numberOfToppings = 0;
}
//prompt for mushroom and store in numberOfToppings
System.out.println("Would you like mushroom added? (Y/N): ");
numberOfToppings = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
if (numberOfToppings == "Y" || numberOfToppings == 'y') {
  numberOfToppings = numberOfToppings + 1;
  toppings = toppings + "and mushroom.";
} else {
  numberOfToppings = 0;
}
```

Well I expected that it would compile and that I would be able to test my program but it seems that when I try to compile the error message being produced is

```
PizzaOrder.java:90: error: bad operand types for binary operator '=='
    if (numberOfToppings == "Y" || numberOfToppings == 'y') {
                         ^
  first type:  int
  second type: String
PizzaOrder.java:99: error: bad operand types for binary operator '=='
    if (numberOfToppings == "Y" || numberOfToppings == 'y') {
                         ^
  first type:  int
  second type: String
PizzaOrder.java:108: error: bad operand types for binary operator '=='
    if (numberOfToppings == "Y" || numberOfToppings == 'y') {
                         ^
  first type:  int
  second type: String
PizzaOrder.java:117: error: bad operand types for binary operator '=='
    if (numberOfToppings == "Y" || numberOfToppings == 'y') {
                         ^
  first type:  int
  second type: String
4 errors
```

Comment: `"Y"` is a `String`. Everywhere you used `"Y"`, use `'Y'` which is a `char` (and would work).

Comment: In that case would you suggest instead of numberOfToppings = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0); replace it with char = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);

Comment: You need to review your own study materials. Because that is not a legal statement in Java, and your compiler errors will not go away on their own.

Comment: Um, you're using `numberOfToppings` to both read in yes/no input _and_ to count up the number of toppings?  You need **two different variables** for the **two different purposes**.

Answer (score 0):

You were using the same variable for different things. 
For when comparing Strings use `.equals()` not `==` also you can't compare different types of variables. 
If you want to increment a variable by one you could do this `i++` it's the same as `i = i + 1` and `i += 1`. The `+=` also works with Strings but I'd recommend using StringBuilder. In the else statement you were initializing the variable back to `0` not adding `0` it would be redundant to add `0` so might as well do nothing.

Here is the code:

```
    int numberOfToppings = 0;
    String toppings = "";
    String choice;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Would you like pepperoni added? (Y/N): ");
    choice = keyboard.nextLine();
    if (choice.equals("Y") || choice.equals("y")) {
        numberOfToppings++;
        toppings += "+ pepperoni\n";
    }
//Prompt for sausage and store in numberOfToppings
        System.out.println("Would you like sausage added? (Y/N): ");
        choice = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (choice.equals("Y") || choice.equals("y")) {
            numberOfToppings++;
            toppings += "+ sausage\n";
        }
//prompt for onion and store in numberOfToppings
        System.out.println("Would you like onion added? (Y/N): ");
        choice = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (choice.equals("Y") || choice.equals("y")) {
            numberOfToppings++;
            toppings += "+ onion\n";
        }
//prompt for mushroom and store in numberOfToppings
        System.out.println("Would you like mushroom added? (Y/N): ");
        choice = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (choice.equals("Y") || choice.equals("y")) {
            numberOfToppings++;
            toppings += "+ mushroom\n";
        }

    System.out.println("Number of Toppings :  " + numberOfToppings);
    System.out.println("Toppings : \n" + toppings);
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying what the flaw was.